# How to turn a docker container to a zombie

Tags: docker, zombie-process

A few years ago. When I just started playing docker. I remember there are some blog posts mentioned if you don't handle your pid(1) process well. You will create a zombie docker container. At that time. I chose just follow the suggestion start using a init tool called [dumb-init](https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init). And I never really see a zombie container be created.

But I am still curious why it's a problem. If I remember correctly, `docker stop xxx` by default will send `SIGTERM` to the container pid(1) process. And if the process can not gracefully stop within 10s (default). Docker will force kill it by sending `SIGKILL` to pid(1) process. And I also know that pid(1) process is special in Linux system. It can ignore `SIGKILL` signal ([link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7441/can-root-kill-init-process)). But I think even if the process's PID in docker container is 1. It just because it's using namespaces to scope its processes. In the host machine, you should see the process is another PID. Which can be killed by the kernel.

So my questions are:

1. Why can't docker engine just kill the container in the host kernel level? So no matter what. The user can ensure the container be killed properly.
2. How can I create a zombie process in docker container? (If someone can share a Gist will be great!)

Comment: Start a long running faulty background process in an entrypoint script, then call `wait()`... The container will remain alive, but that other process will die

Answer (score 0):

Not zombie *containers*, but zombie *processes*.  Write this `zombie.py`:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time

p = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/sleep', '1'])
time.sleep(2)

subprocess.run(['/bin/ps', '-ewl'])
```

Write this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3
COPY zombie.py /
CMD ["/zombie.py"]
```

Build and run it:

```sh
chmod +x zombie.py
docker build -t zombie .
docker run --rm zombie
```

What happens here is the `/bin/sleep` command runs to execution.  The parent process needs to use the `wait` call to clean up after it, but it doesn't so when it runs `ps`, you'll see a "Z" zombie process.

But wait, there's more!  Say your process does carefully clean up after itself.  In this specific example, `subprocess.run()` includes the required `wait` call, for instance, and you might change the `Popen` call to `run`.  If that subprocess launches another subprocess, and *it* exits (or crashes) without waiting for it, the init process with pid 1 becomes the new parent process of the zombie.  (It's worked this way for 40 years.)  In a Docker container, though, the main container process runs with pid 1, and if it's not expecting "extra" child processes, you could wind up with stale zombie processes for the life of the container.

This leads to the occasional suggestion that a Docker container should always run some sort of "real" init process, maybe something as minimal as [tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini), so that something picks up after zombie processes and your actual container job doesn't need to worry about it.